# Memory Errors - Right Join If Null Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, left-join

I'm trying to make a right join if null between two very large dataset, and I am encountering memory errors both in my laptop and on Google Cloud with a 128gb ram machine (largest RAM I could get in Europe).

```py
A_sold = (product_all.merge(A, on='Produktnummer', how='right', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge == "right_only"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))
A_sold.drop_duplicates(subset=['Produktnummer'], keep='first', inplace=True)
A_sold
```

Is there any way to perform it locally in Python out of core?

Comment: You can increase swap size. Or Segment the data into smaller batches (merge monthly data rather than yearly, for example). You can use a larger managed DB service such as big query. If the data is nicely sorted, you can look into open source columnar DB ClickHouse and try to join files rather than mem

Comment: this is definitely a use-case for Pyspark or a SQL database. I'd also look into Dask.

Comment: @Datanovice thanks. I ended up activating my account and using a 200Gb RAM machine on Google Cloud. I still have room since they offer several Tb of RAM if needed, but I should start looking into storing my data on SQL. Thanks again!